# Как убрать все брекпоинты разом phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Как убрать все брекпоинты разом phpstorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ctrl+Shift+F8 должно открыть окно со всеми бряками, дальше выделяешь нужные и удаляешь.
2. Так же можно попасть в это окно открыв вкладку Debug и кликнуть в ней на кнопку с двумя пересекающимися красными кружочками:

[image]

3. В меню Run есть кнопка ViewBreakpoints

[image]